# How can I find the list of tags I created?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know if I can find the list of tags I created in the past.

Do you know if it's possible?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't found a way of doing it.  If it were available at all, it would probably be available through the tags API: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags  However, there is no way there to filter tags by creator.

Comment: Thanks Stephen but it doesn't help.